# How can I iterate through a list within the dictionary and run the command for each index?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary which has index number as the key and a list of 5 integers in the values. I want to run a set command so as to set the speed for 0th element of the list for all the index numbers one by one and then repeat the same for the other elements based on the indexes as well. I am achieve the same by running it through the range of the list elements. Can anyone help to achieve this?
following is the dictionary

```
dict = {0: [13440, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 1: [14310, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 2: [13410, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 3: [14130, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 4: [13380, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 5: [14280, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 6: [13500, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 7: [14190, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 8: [9150, 3000, 3800, 4800, 6000, 8500], 9: [8670, 3000, 3800, 4800, 6000, 8500]}

for index, speeds in dict.items():
    for i in range(len(speeds)):
        cmd = 'set %d speed %s' % (index, speeds[i])
        print(cmd)
```

I am expecting the cmd to run through the 0th element of the list for index 0,1,2,3....8,9. And similary it should run for 1st element for all the indexes and so on one by one. So, basically it should set the  first speed of each index number first then the second speed of each index number and so on. Hope my question is clear.
Current output which I am getting is this

```
set 0 speed 13440
set 0 speed 7000
set 0 speed 8800
set 0 speed 11000
set 0 speed 15000
set 1 speed 14310
.
.
. 
set 9 speed 8500
```

I am expecting something like

```
set 0 speed 13440
set 1 speed 14310
set 2 speed 13410
set 3 speed 14130
.
.
and so on
```

Comment: What specifically is the problem with the code you posted?

Comment: Attached the output which I am getting and the desired output @kaya3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine the maximum length of the lists within `dict` and iterate over each index in the outer loop, while looping over `dict`'s keys in the inner loop. Watch out for lists that have smaller length than the maximum.

**Edit**: Added sleep between speed changes using [time.sleep](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep). Changed variable names to be more descriptive.

```
import time

dict = {0: [13440, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 1: [14310, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 2: [13410, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 3: [14130, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 4: [13380, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 5: [14280, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 6: [13500, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 7: [14190, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 8: [9150, 3000, 3800, 4800, 6000, 8500], 9: [8670, 3000, 3800, 4800, 6000, 8500]}

# The maximum length of dict's lists of speeds
max_speed_count = max(len(lst) for lst in dict.values())

for speed_index in range(max_speed_count):
    for fan_index in dict:
        # If one of the lists has smaller length, catch the error and continue
        try:
            speed = dict[fan_index][speed_index]
        except IndexError:
            continue
        
        cmd = 'fan_set %d speed %s' % (fan_index, speed)
        print(cmd)

    # Sleep for a minute between speed changes
    time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: It was greatly helpful. There is one more step after this though which I am not sure how to achieve. So, after setting the fan speed for all the indexes with the 0th element of the list I need to introduce a delay of 1 min and then run for 1st element for all the indexes and so on. Is it possible @Božo Stojković?

Comment: You just need to `import time` and use `time.sleep` that takes seconds to sleep as an argument. @Jayashri

Comment: Though the code does exactly what you described. Maybe you didn't copy it over correctly? Watch out for indentation.